# Basis of a vector field on a manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have seen vector fields $X$ on a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ defined as
$$
X = X_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}
$$
where $X_{i}$ are smooth functions $X_{i} : U \to \mathbb{R}$ with $U \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ a neighbourhood in $\mathcal{M}$. I know that the set
$$
\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} \right\}
$$
forms a basis for the tangent space of $\mathcal{M}$ at a point $x \in \mathcal{M}$, so any element of the tangent space would be a linear combination of the partial differentials. However, I don't see why the coefficient of the basis elements are *functions* when $X$ is a vector field. Moreover, I'm unsure of how to use this basis with explicit vector fields.

For example, given $x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}) \in S^{3} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{4}$, write
$$
v(x) = (-x_{2}, x_{1}, -x_{4}, x_{3}).
$$
Then $v$ is a vector field on $S^{3}$, but I can't figure out what each $v_{i}$ would be if one were to write $v$ as a linear combination
$$
v = v_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}, \hspace{25pt} v_{i} : U \to \mathbb{R}
$$
where $U$ is an open neighbourhood about $x$ in $S^{3}$.

I appreciate that there is a difference between the global coordinates of $x$ (expressed as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ using four coordinates) and the local coordinates of $x$ (expressed as an element of $S^{3}$ using three coordinates), but I am still learning how to use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see why the coefficient of the basis elements are functions when $X$ is a vector field.

This is like writing a vector field in 3d in terms of the basis $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$.  A vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ attaches to every point $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ another vector.  You sometimes see vector fields written $(f(\vec{v}), g(\vec{v}), h(\vec{v}))$, showing that you get the "attached" vector back for any input $\vec{v}$.  The components are scalar functions of a vector variable.  You could instead write this as $f(\vec{v})\hat{x} + g(\vec{v})\hat{y} + h(\vec{v})\hat{z}$ and it means the exact same thing, but here it looks a bit more like the definition you gave.

For your $S^3$ example, note that $S^3$ is a three-manifold.  It will probably help you to find *three* rather than *four* local coordinates for $S^3$.  Can you write the fourth in terms of the first three? Where can you do that?  A vector field is going to be an assignment of some vector $v$ in the tangent space $T_p M$ for every $p \in M$.  The tangent space at any point on $S^3$ will be three dimensional, having basis $\partial/\partial{x_1}$, $\partial/\partial{x_2}$, $\partial/\partial{x_3}$ for your choice of *three* coordinates for $S^3$.

When you write $v(x)=(−x_2,x_1,−x_4,x_3)$ you assign a four-vector to every point on a three-manifold.  Now, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ this may very well be a vector field: each $v(x)$ could lie in the tangent plane to $S^3$ at $x$.  But (and I haven't calculated) it could also point in a direction with a normal component to $S^3$.  Such a vector is not in the tangent space at $x$, and therefore $v$ would not be a vector field of $S^3$.

Imagine you are a creature (like an ant) inhabiting the sphere $S^2$.  At any point there are only two dimensions you can explore (forward/backward or left/right).  A third direction (like up/down) would make no sense to you.  Therefore if you are restricted to live in $S^2$ your velocity can be described by two numbers. This is the idea of intrinsic geometry: using coordinates $\partial/\partial{x_i}$ you guarantee that you are only describing vector fields *on your manifold* and not just restrictions of vector fields in some ambient space.